# jquery serialize()+custom?

Tags: jquery, serialization

When using $.POST and $.GET in jquery is there any way to add custom vars to the URL and send them too?
i tried the following :

```
$.ajax({type:"POST", url:"file.php?CustomVar=data", data:$("#form").serialize()});
```

And :

```
<input name="CustomVar" type="hidden" value="data" />
$.ajax({type:"POST", url:"file.php", data:$("#form").serialize()});
```

The first ones problem is that it send the custom as get but i want to receive it as post.
The second one well i'm using it right now but there is not any better way?

Answer (score 8):

[Internally](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js#L83), [`.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) does a [`$.param()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) on [`.serializeArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) so you can do that yourself adding whatever you want in-between, like this:

```
var obj = $("#form").serializeArray();
obj.CustomVar = 'someValue';
$.ajax({ type:"POST", url:"file.php", data:$.param(obj) });
```

Comment: This is out of date now. Doesn't work anymore.
The output of obj now is:-
 [Object { name="q",  value=""}, Object { name="type",  value="PC"}, Object { name="schedule",  value="2015-12-11 01:00:00 PM"}, Object { name="pId",  value="test"}...etc.